# Android TabHost transparent background and show underneath list

Tags: android, android-layout, fragment-tab-host

I searched a lot about this issue and applied those solutions but couldn't succeed. I need to apply transparency to FragmentTabHost and show whatever underneath that TabHost.

I also applied transparent color to all the five tabs 1 by 1, but that doesn't effect.
Thanks in advance.

XML Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/transparent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/homeToolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/red">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:text="@string/home"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textStyle="normal" />


        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/realtabcontent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost
        android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
        android:background="@color/transparent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:background="@drawable/tab_background"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0" />
    </android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost>

</LinearLayout>
```